# Direct3DCreate9 Hook

Tags: delphi

The code works, but i can't figure out how to return back to the real function.

```
procedure PatchInCallTo(Where: DWORD; CallTo: DWORD; nops: Integer = 0);
var
  PB: array[0..4+10] of byte;
  offset: DWORD;
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i:=0 to PRED(sizeof(PB)) do
    PB[i]:=$90;
  offset:=CallTo - Where - 5;
  PB[0]:=$E8; // E8 = call - E9 = jump
  PDWORD(@PB[1])^:=offset;
  Patch(Where, DWORD(@PB), 5 + nops);
end;

type
  PDirect3DCreate9 = function(SDKVersion: LongWord): Pointer; stdcall;
var
  RealDirect3DCreate9: PDirect3DCreate9;

function NewDirect3DCreate9(SDKVersion: LongWord): Pointer; stdcall;
begin
  try
    Log('Direct3DCreate9: Invoked. SDKVersion = '+IntToHex(DWORD(Pointer(SDKVersion)), 8));
    Result := RealDirect3DCreate9(SDKVersion);
  except
    Log('Direct3DCreate9: Hook failed.');
  end;
end;

procedure DllMain(reason: integer);
var
  hDirectX: Dword;
begin
  case reason of
  DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    begin
      hDirectX := DWORD(GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary('d3d9.dll'), 'Direct3DCreate9'));
      Log('d3d9.dll - Module Handle: '+IntToHex(GetModuleHandle('d3d9.dll'),8)+' - Direct3DCreate9 GetProcAddress: '+IntToHex(Integer(hDirectX),8));
      RealDirect3DCreate9 := GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary('d3d9.dll'), 'Direct3DCreate9');
      PatchInCallTo(hDirectX, DWORD(@NewDirect3DCreate9));
    end;
  DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    begin
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The hook is fine, the NewDirect3DCreate9 function gets called, however it loops and does not return to the real function.

Log file looks as follows:

```
d3d9.dll - Module Handle: 67E50000 - Direct3DCreate9 GetProcAddress: 67E93F60
Direct3DCreate9: Invoked. SDKVersion = 08ED9A75
Direct3DCreate9: Invoked. SDKVersion = 08ED9A75
Direct3DCreate9: Invoked. SDKVersion = 08ED9A75
Direct3DCreate9: Invoked. SDKVersion = 08ED9A75
Direct3DCreate9: Invoked. SDKVersion = 08ED9A75
Direct3DCreate9: Invoked. SDKVersion = 08ED9A75
Direct3DCreate9: Invoked. SDKVersion = 08ED9A75
Direct3DCreate9: Invoked. SDKVersion = 08ED9A75
Direct3DCreate9: Invoked. SDKVersion = 08ED9A75
Direct3DCreate9: Invoked. SDKVersion = 08ED9A75
```

Comment: Inside your hook procedure you should remove the patch, call original procedure, then install patch again. By the way, there is good library for hooking in Delphi: https://github.com/mahdisafsafi/delphi-detours-library

Comment: You need a trampoline. Use a good library.

Comment: After reviewing some source code from the detour library i have managed successfully trampoline without using the library. Appreciate the help guys, if you want me to throw up the solution i came up with, i can paste bin it. I understand now where i was going wrong.